# How to find earlier date in google spreadsheets?

Tags: google-sheets

in Google Spreadsheets I have a column A with dates and column B with specific values corresponding these dates:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 10-Jan | 51.1 |
| 11-Jan | 49.2 |
| 14-Jan | 50.3 |

If I find via VLOOKUP function the value of 11-Jan, it will work and show 49.2.
Off cause it won't work if I try to find a value of 13-Jan since it is absent from the list of dates. However, if the date is absent in column A I want to get the value of earlier date which is in the list (i.e. I want to get 49.2 corresponding to 11-Jan, if I use 13-Jan as the query for finding the value).

Maybe this type of search can be realized by using INDIRECT function, but I can't figure out the formula.

How do realize this?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem can be solved by using `vlookup` only but with different parameter, if you indicate `True` for the last parameter, it mean the formula will try to return the closer match if it cannot found any result.

```
=arrayformula(VLOOKUP(E1:E5,A:B,2,True))
```

[image]